# Unknown type name 'sll'. Issue with structs

Tags: c

I am new to C and am having issues with my structs being listed as unknown types. I cannot change the method signatures as they are written by my professor and he will be linking into them from external code.

```
sll.c:6:1: error: unknown type name 'sll'
sll *newSLL(void (*d)(FILE *, void*)) { 
in function 'newSLL';
```

EDIT: added the actual error

HEADER FILE:

```
#ifndef __SLL_INCLUDED__
#define __SLL_INCLUDED__

typedef struct sllnode {
    void *value;
    struct sllnode *next;
} sllnode;

typedef struct sll {
    sllnode *head;
    sllnode *tail;
    int size;
    void (*display)(FILE *,void *);
} sll;

extern sll *newSLL(void (*d)(FILE *,void *));
```

C FILE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct sllnode {
    void *value;
    struct sllnode *next;
} *sllnode;

struct sll {
    struct sllnode *head;
    struct sllnode *tail;
    int size;
    void (*display)(FILE *,void *);
} *sll;

sll *newSLL(void (*d)(FILE *,void *)) {
    struct sll *items = malloc(sizeof(sll));
    if (items == 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"out of memory");
        exit(-1);
    }

    items->head = 0;
    items->tail = 0;
    items->size = 0;
    items->display = d;
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the actual errors you get, in full and unedited. Copy-paste them into the question as text. Then when you're updating the question, please indicate *where* in the source you get the error, for example by a comment.

Comment: But as a hint: You have two symbols named `sllnode` but that mean different things. Same thing with `sll`.

Comment: Note that using a name such as `__SLL_INCLUDED__` in code you write is not a good idea.  All names beginning with double underscore, or an underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation to use.  You see such names in system headers because they're part of the implementation and implementers are required to use such names not to trample on the namespace reserved for users; you should reciprocate and not trample on the namespace reserved for the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your C file never included the header file, so the type `ssl` is not defined.

You need to include your header at the top of the C file.  You then need to remove the `struct` definitions from the C file since they're already defined in the header.